# Need to check wildcard characters using regex

Tags: java, regex

i am checking not allowed charters from input string

```
protected static Boolean validateWildcardCharacters(String inputText) {
    List<String> term = Arrays.asList("!","@","#","$","%","^","&","(",")","_","+","=",";",";","{","}","[","]","'","<",">",",",".","|");
    Boolean containChar = false;
    for(String ch : term){
        if(inputText.contains(ch)) {
            containChar = true;
            break;
        }
    };
    return containChar;
```

But I am looking for some better solution. Maybe using Regular expression (regex).

please suggest better approach to do that. 
Thanks

Comment: A better approach would be to store not allowed characters in `HashSet<Character>` and iterate over `inputText` as inputText.toCharArray(). As the first found in the HashSet will exit the implementation. How the approach helps? O(1) lookups with HashSet for each Character and iterating the Complete inputText only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a regular expression, you need to use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes from `java.util.regex`. Here is an example on how you could use it:

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "Your string here : { } . / []";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[!@#$%^&*(),.?\":{}|<>\\[\\]]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
    if (matcher.find())
        System.out.println("found");
    else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
}
```